# Sort list of String based on it's value in given map

Tags: scala

I have one String list

```
val str = List("A","B","C","D")
```

and given:

```
val map = Map(("A"->3),("B"->1),("C"->10),("D"->5))
```

To sort str list based on given map value, I have tried `str.sortBy(map)`. It's giving me error `"A" key is not found`. Could someone please help me out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works as is for me.

Comment: You may want to use `getOrElse` instead to provide a default value for missing keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work as it is. Let's explain why. The signature of `sortBy` is:

```
def sortBy[B](f: A => B)(implicit ord: Ordering[B]): C = sorted(ord on f)
```

Therefore when you do `str.sortBy(map)`, `sortBy` expects to get `String => Int`. `str.sortBy(map)` is equivalent to:

```
str.sortBy(s => map(s))
```

Note that [`Map` extends `MapOps`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/Map.scala#L24)(in Scala 2.13, in Scala 2.12 it is [MapLike](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/MapLike.scala)). `MapOps`(and `MapLike`) exposes an [`apply`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/Map.scala#L142) method, which takes (in your case) `String` and returns `Int`:

```
def apply(key: K): V = get(key) match {
  case None => default(key)
  case Some(value) => value
}
```

Hence writing `str.sortBy(map)` is the same as:

```
str.sortBy(s => map.apply(s))
```

which is the same as:

```
str.sortBy(map.apply)
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/ygXJwQkFTWWiygkUI3AIuA/10).