# How should I get B form A => B

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm new to Scala, and I'm running into this strange situation.

```scala
def bar[A, B](implicit foo: A => B): B = {
  // do something
  foo
}
```

And then I got error like

```
require B but found A => B
```

How should I get B form A => B

Here's the reason why I did this, I have two functions:

```scala
def funcA: String = {
  def getStrA: String = "A"

  // then there's the same operation in both functions
  Try{  } match {
    case Success(_) => getStrA
    case Failure(_) => // exactlly same error handler in both function
  }
  
}
def funcB: Int = {
  def doSomething(x: Int): Int = {
    // do something
    x / 1
  }
  
  val x = 1
  Try{  } match {
    case Success(_) => doSomething(1)
    case Failure(_) => // exactlly same error handler in both function
  }
}
```

Here's what I want to achieve

```scala
def funcA: String = {
  implicit def getStrA: String = "A"

  bar  
}
def funcB: Int = {
  val x = 1
  implicit def doSomething(x: Int): Int = {
    // do something
    x / 1
  }
  
  bar
}

def bar[A, B](implicit foo: A => B): B = {
  Try{  } match {
    case Success(_) => foo
    case Failure(_) => // exactlly same error handler in both function
  }
}
```

Comment: Call `foo()` passing a value of type `A`.

Comment: then how should I call this ```bar``` function

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65758505/2359227) might be helpful for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a conversion from `A` to `B`. You need to return `B`. The only way to do this is to pass `A` into the function. This signature has an implied assumption that you have some valid `A` value (most likely hardcoded) that you will always use here.

```
def bar[A, B](implicit foo: A => B): B = {
  val a: A = ... // hmm...
  foo(a)
}
```

Considering, that `A` is parametric, then you are either missing some information, or this `A` is impossible to create (it cannot be `null` because not all types can take `null` as a value), so you might need to throw exception in such case. Probably you are either missing some `A` provider or you should always fail this operation.

UPDATE:

There is no need for using implicits at all in your code:

```
def bar[B](f: onSuccess: A => B) = 
  Try{ some operations } match {
    case Success(value) => onSuccess(value)
    case Failure(_)     => // error handler 
  }

def funcA = bar(_ => "A")
def funcB = bar(_ => 1)
```

Comment: You mean I should pass this `a` to ```bar``` function?

Comment: If you can figure out the `A` then yes, if you cannot then you cannot create `B`.

Comment: But I still need `A` to be parametric, and I don't want to pass this `A` to `bar` explicitly. How should I do it.

Comment: You could take some implicit `A`, or some implicit `trait Provider[A] { def provide: A }`. Or you can define this function on some object that is parametric on `[A]` have method parametric on `B` and stores value of `A`. If you cannot do any of that, then you have definition that cannot be implemented in other way as never returning value (so throwing exception or exiting).

Comment: I updated this question with my full problem, please check is out

Comment: 1). Pass `A` as implicit. 2). This is very overengeeniered anty-pattern as there is not need for implicits in your code. Eveything could be implemented clearer using higer-order functions.

Comment: I checked high-order function in this link [link](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/higher-order-functions.html) but I still can't find a way to achieve it.

Comment: I posted update with an example. If it still doesn't help you, create a Scastie with a working example of your original code, with all the signatures.